# Online 3D house viewer

Tags: 3d, viewer, 3ds

Are there any good online 3D viewers which can render an house in modern browsers?

It needs to support .3ds format.

Or is this still something for the future?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, [X3D](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X3D) is an XML-based 3D file format. It can be embedded inside the browser DOM, enabling it to display 3D geometry. See [this](http://www.x3dom.org/check/).

I'll point out the obvious, that you will need to export your .3ds to X3D somehow, in order to use this feature.